# Collect clinical information from the ADNI

Tags: database, image, collect, mri

**Hi scientists!**

I need to collect a number of PET-MR images from the ADNI website. I need to measure the SUVR values (Standardized Uptake Value) and compare two groups.
My problem is I cannot find the height and weight of the subjects, and I need them to measure the SUVR.
Do you know if ADNI provides these two information for the subjects? and how may I find them?

**Thanks in advance,
Taha**